# Mongodb compare two big data collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-java

I want to compare two very big collection, the main of the operation is two know what element is change or deleted
My collection 1 and 2 have a same structure and have more 3 million records
example :
record 1 `{id:'7865456465465',name:'tototo', info:'tototo'}`

So i want to know : what element is change, and what element is not present in collection 2.
What is the best solution to do this?

Comment: do you know for sure that some document was changed?

Comment: Asya, Yes i want to know if a element is deleted or is changed.

Comment: Just start looping through each, tracking success/failures. There's no better option than brute force comparisons.

Comment: untrue - if there were no changes you waste a lot of time that way.

Comment: Yes Asya Kamsky, it is no possible to looping each record it is very long process.

Answer (score 0):

1) Define what equality of 2 documents means. For me it would be: both documents should contain all fields with exact same values given their ids are unique. Note that mongo does not guarantee field order, and if you update a field it might move to the end of the document which is fine.

2) I would use some framework that can connect to mongo and fetch data at the same time converting it to a map-like data structure or even JSON. For instance I would go with Scala + Lift record (db.coll.findAll()) + Lift JSON. Lift JSON library has Diff function that will give you a diff of 2 JSON docs.

3) Finally I would sort both collections by ids, open db cursors, iterate and compare.

Answer (score 0):

if the schema is flat in your case it is, you can use a free tool to compare the data(dataq.io) in two tables.

Disclaimer : I am the founder of this product.